# Using swagger annotation to set dataType to a nested container

Tags: swagger

Using swagger's @ApiModelProperty, how can one set the type of a field to array[array[double]] ? I am using swagger 1.3

Comment: Time to upgrade to 1.5.

Comment: Well, is there any annotation that allows me to do that, I can't find anything in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations

Comment: You don't need an annotation for it. The field type should represent it.